# Bit shifting x * a number

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

How do you get number like `-10` from these bit shifting practice problems?

From what I understand `X*32` can be written as `x<<5`. But how are you to get numbers like `x*66`, or `X*(-10)`?

Answer (score 3):

**General Explanation**

Bit shifting is primarily aimed to shift the binary representation of a number. It is **not** for multiplication.

```
23 = 0001 0111
23 << 1 = 0001 0111 << 1 = 0010 1110 = 46
```

> However, as the binary representation of a number is changed, the
>   number it represents is also changed. This is just how computer binary system works. And thus people sometimes exploit this behavior as a "hack", mostly to speed up the computation time.

Let's try to understand it more:

---

**Left bit-shift and right bit-shift**

Now, when the number represented is of `integer` type, then shifting the binary representation of a number by 1 to the **left** will be equivalent to **multiplying** it by 2:

```
23 = 0001 0111
23 << 1 = 0001 0111 << 1 = 0010 1110 = 46 //left bit-shift by 1, number becomes doubled
```

Given that there is **no overflow** for the given data type:

```
255 = 1111 1111 //assuming 8-bit data type
255 << 1 = 1111 1111 << 1 = 1111 1110 = 254 //not multiplied by 2, because of overflow
```

While shifting integer number to the **right** will be equivalent as **dividing** it by 2 and then **rounding it down**:

```
23 = 0001 0111
23 >> 1 = 0001 0111 >> 1 = 000 1011 = 11 //right bit-shift by 1, number becomes halved, rounded down
```

---

**Some use and link to multiplication and division**

Since bit-shifting operation is typically less costly than multiplication, to speed things up, you will see in some program, people use left bit-shift operation (as a replacement of multiplication) when they mean to multiply it by `an integer number of power of 2` (that is 2, 4, 8, 16, etc):

```
int a = 23;
...
a = a << 2; //=102; multiply by 4, equivalent to a = a * 4, but faster operation
```

Or use right bit-shift operation (as a replacement of division and rounding down) to divide it with `an integer number of power of 2` (that is 2, 4, 8, 16, etc)

```
int a = 23;
...
a = a >> 2; //=5; divide by 4 and rounding down, equivalent to integer division a = a / 4, but faster
```

---

**Concluding remarks**

Note that only if you operate with number with power of 2, all the multiplications and divisions above can be replaced by left bit-shift or right bit-shift.

In your example, 66 and -10 are not integer number which of power of 2, thus you cannot "hack" the multiplication/division with binary-shifting operation.

In general, use bit-shift operation if you mean for bit-shifting, as bit-shifting has many other uses than just "hacking" for multiplication/division with integer number of power of 2. If you want to multiply or divide, be happy with just using multiplication (`*`) or division (`/`) operator.

---

**Some additional remarks:**

That being said, I would just like to add some more things regarding the bit-shift for further explanation (it won't do harm):

- signed `integer` type can hold positive **or negative** number
- there is a difference between logical bit-shift and arithmetic bit-shift when dealing with negative number. One will give `0` in the emptied-space after shift while the other will give `1`
- Hence, it probably best to note that the bit-shift is mainly used for `unsigned` type, such like for creating bit-masks by bit shifting. That is, `unsigned` is recommended to be used to avoid sign-extension surprises when you deal with negative number (right) bit-shift.

Comment: Probably ought to emphasize that shifting is generally done on `unsigned` values to avoid sign-extension surprises, etc.. Otherwise, great explanation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ah yes, I probably should put up some more remarks regarding that...