# how we can determine the type of a variable declared with var key word in c#

Tags: c#, .net

1. I want to get input from user and print the type of the input given by user.
2. I have tried this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var userObj = Console.ReadLine();

        // if input is 5 it should print it is of type int.

        //if input is 5.4 it should print it is of type double.
        Console.WriteLine(userObj.GetType());// printing only string

    }
}
```

---

also tried this but always going false

```
using System;
class Solution
{

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var userObj = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.Format(userObj) == string .Format("0"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("it is of type interger");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to attempt to parse the string into each type. `5` is a perfectly valid value for a `double` as well as `int`, so the answer is ambiguous. Your code would turn into `if (int.TryParse(userObj, out var _)) { Console.WriteLine("int"); } else if (double.TryParse(...` and so on.

Comment: @Rob is right, since `Console.ReadLine()` always gives you a string, you would need to try parsing to each of the types you are looking for (e.g. DateTime, int, etc). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36350473/6741868) could help you.

Comment: @Rob thanks its working.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how `var` works in C#. C# is a strongly-typed language and as such it's not the same as other languages that use `var` like JavaScript. Therefore, the variable declared as var already knows what type it is at **compile** time.

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, therefore the variable `userObj` in this sense WILL be a string. You will never get anything but a string type.

You can, however, try several things to see if you can convert it to another type. for example:

```
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
int x;
if(int.TryParse(userInput, out x))
{
    Console.WriteLine("That's an int!");
}
```

Comment: This is working well, also expanded it for double and float. but got a review of poor design and language, upon submission in a code challenge, Is there any way to improve the design of this code or to make use of some other possible methods.

Comment: Without knowing the full details of your challenge there isn't a whole lot more to add except maybe a loop that asks again upon invalid input and expanding types to include other data types as you mention like floats/doubles. It's a pretty basic task.

Answer (score 0):

Try parse some with some different number datatypes from biggest to smallest. I assume you want to store the number in the smallest one possible.

```
float var1;
double var2;
int var3;

if (float.TryParse(urMom, out var1))
    Console.WriteLine("Float");
else if (double.TryParse(urMom, out var2))
    Console.WriteLine("Double");
else if (int.TryParse(urMom, out var3))
    Console.WriteLine("Int");
```

Comment: `urMom`, very mature. Also, you're using `TryParse` wrong, allow me to edit.

Comment: This `var1 != null` produces a compiler warning because `float` can't ever be equal to null

Comment: You can inline your declarations to make things a little more readable, e.g. `int.TryParse(longNumber, out int result); Trace.WriteLine(result);`

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih: Well, it depends on the version of the C# compiler you're using. I'd expect it to still work when targeting .NET 2.0...

Comment: @Jon Skeet oh, yeah, you're right. That's a C#7 language feature. My bad.